# Why should I use HttpClient over fetch?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

Angular 2+ introduces `HttpClient` which makes an HTTP request and sends them down an RxJS observable. My question is why would I choose to use [`HttpClient`'s API](https://angular.io/guide/http) over the standard [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for making single HTTP requests?

I'm familiar with RxJS and I understand this chart of ["the four fundamental effects"](https://youtu.be/sTSQlYX5DU0?t=6m39s).

```
       | one        | many
-------------------------------------
sync   |  T         | Iterable<T>
async  | Promise<T> | Observable<T>
```

Http requests are async and return one value. Why should that be a Observable? I understand wanting to compose a stream of events into a stream of HTTP *requests* but I don't understand why I would want to use a stream of just one HTTP *response*. Isn't that just like using an array when you only have one value?

Am I missing something? In general, why should I use Angular's HttpClient? Where does fetch fall short?

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/447

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a different API. Observables have a better way to separate "how things flow" (all operators: map, merge, concat, etc.) vs executing that (.subscribe), which often helps to get a better picture. Plus provides useful methods for cancelling or retrying a request if it fails.

And you can always use `firstValueFrom(observeable)` if you need the Promise API (to use async/await, which is really useful as well)

So for me it's just two ways of representing the same thing, each one has its advantatges over the other, but as Observable is more generic they used that - You can convert back and forth from Observable to Promise, but Observables bring features that Promises doesn't have.

Comment: HttpClient also provides mocking facilities for unit testing.

Comment: @bnieland I think your answer is more relevant to OP... because with mine you could then argue to use an Rx.Observable-version of fetch (if that does exist).