# Why to use observables instead of Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, rxjs

Why should I use an HTTP observable method like this:

```
this.http.get("MyURL")
         .subscribe(
            (_url: any) => {
                //TODO My job
            },
            (error: any) => {
                //TODO My job
            },
            () => {
                //TODO My job
            });
```

Instead of use an AJAX method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MyURL",
    success: function (result) {
        //TODO My job
    },
    error: function () {
        //TODO My job
    }
});
```

I mean, what are the benefits and harms?

Comment: The most obvious reason would be that the first one is angular directive while the later one is based on jQuery... In the end they both do the same thing, so i think its a matter of application design and preference.. If you are already using angular i would so go with angular directives as much as possible tho

Comment: @MKougiouris in this case `http` is a provider / service and not a directive :)

Comment: @MKougiouris What is an Angular Directive in this case? Sorry fba_pereira, there is no Angular directive in your question.

Comment: "directive" was an inappropriate word. I meant that the first approach is based on angular's observables, as in something belonging to angular already, instead of an external lib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use HttpClient over fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505072/why-should-i-use-httpclient-over-fetch)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why would you use an external library to do something angular is already capable of? Why would you actually use jQuery at all in combination with angular?

I think a better title for your question would have been, why use observables at all. I have had the same question when I started with angular, but after working with angular for over a year and having worked a lot with observables and `rxjs` over that period of time I have learned the following.

1- You cannot cancel promises

Lets say somebody goes to screen A, and you fetch some data like so.

```
fetch(/** some end point */)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(() => {
    // Handle the request here
  });
```

And by the time you are able to handle the request, the user leaves screen A. In most cases that is not a big deal, but because you want to do things the best way possible you would preferably cancel the handling of the request. With native promises, that's simply impossible. Read [this](https://medium.com/@benlesh/promise-cancellation-is-dead-long-live-promise-cancellation-c6601f1f5082) article for great explantion on this

With observables, this becomes trivial. You can unsubscribe from an observable and that will ensure no unnecessary code is executed.

Pro tip: In angular you would do this in the `ngOnDestroy` life cycle of a component.

2 - Native promises have 2 methods, rxjs has many many more.

If you are using the native promises implementation, the only things you can do are `then` and `catch` (on a promise instance). This might seem more than enough, but with rxjs you can do many many more things.

**Example**

Lets say your `/article/:id` end point sometimes returns empty values because there is no article found. In promises your code will look something like this.

```
fetch('/article/5')
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then( res => {
    if ( res !== undefined) {
       // do something!
    }
  });
```

In rxjs this looks much cleaner, in the case of wanting to only do something with the data if its there. This might not seem as a big improvement, but in production you will find yourself wanting to do much much more than filtering out undefined values.

```
this.http.get("MyURL")
     // p.s this line of code might not be needed depending on ur 
     // angular version 
     .map( res => res.json()) 
     .filter( res => res !== undefined)
     .subscribe(res => {
        // Do something!
     });
```

My advice for you would be to use `toPromise` wherever you are doing something simple, and to gradually use more and more rxjs operators once you need them. `map`, `filter` and `takeUntil` would be a good starting point.

I could go on showing you things you can do with rxjs that are hard to implement with promises, but there are lots of articles out there that do a better job than me explaining that.

**TLDR**

You can write cleaner asynchronous code and do more things with less code.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the below link for better information :

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/observables_vs_promises.html

What it seems like it is used majorly because `Observables` can define both the **setup and teardown aspects of asynchronous behavior**.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, they're the same thing. It's really just the implementation and usage that differ, so it becomes a matter of preference really.

`Observables` (which generally refer to the "RxJS" library, though not always) generally have a `subscribe()` method which lets them listen for changes, and have hooks for `onNext()` (something happened), `onError()` (something went wrong), and `onComplete()` (all done).

jQuery's AJAX syntax is a more "classic" callback structure, where you call the function and provide it with callbacks directly. It also has another syntax which allows you to add them as subsequent functions (`.done()` and the like).

When talking about JavaScript specifically though, nowadays I would argue that the `Promise` syntax is the most popular, as it is standardized in ECMAScript 6 and is natively supported by most browsers nowadays. `fetch()` is a native implementation of doing AJAX requests with `Promise` syntax.

At the end of the day, neither is particular better or stronger at the end of the day, and it really just boils down to personal preferences and past experience (for example, `Observables` are popular with developers who have Java experience, since `Observables` are used pretty frequently in Java).

Out of the three, only the Promise one has any real advantage, which is that it is natively supported by modern browsers (whereas the other two require a third-party library). But if you're already using a third-party library for something else, that's not a huge benefit.